# All binding with different index collection items update at the same time WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, wpf-controls

I have code like this in my WPF view ..

```
    <!--Column 2-->
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" >
        <TextBox x:Name="textB2BR0K2" Text="{Binding Path=ListBlok2B[0].B2B1}" />
    </Border>
    <TextBox x:Name="textB2BR1AK2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Path=ListBlok2B[0].B2BR1A}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textB2BR1BK2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding Path=ListBlok2B[0].B2BR1B}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textB2BR1CK2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Text="{Binding Path=ListBlok2B[0].B2BR1C}"/>

    <!--Column 3-->
    <Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" >
        <TextBox x:Name="textB2BR0K3" Text="{Binding Path=ListBlok2B[1].B2B1}" />
    </Border>
    <TextBox x:Name="textB2BR1AK3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Path=ListBlok2B[1].B2BR1A}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textB2BR1BK3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding Path=ListBlok2B[1].B2BR1B}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textB2BR1CK3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" Text="{Binding Path=ListBlok2B[1].B2BR1C}"/>
```

And then I have fill this field from my database from my collection and work properly. But when I try to change one of the value all the data that have some binding attributes changes at the same time 
`ListBlok2B[0].B2BR1A` and `ListBlok2B[1].B2BR1A` changes at the same time when I try to edit inside it..

Anyone knows how to solve this? I want it to bind in different index collection that I have so I can insert it to my database `context.Blok2Bs.insertAllOnSubmit(ListBlok2B)`

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use an itemscontrol and bind your collection to it?

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListBlok2B}>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>     
     <Grid>
      <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" >
         <TextBox x:Name="textB2BR0K2" Text="{Binding Path=B2B1}" />
      </Border>
      <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Path=B2BR1A}"/>
      <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding Path=B2BR1B}"/>
      <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Text="{Binding Path=B2BR1C}"/>

      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I try also with that itemscontrol yesterday but the problems is my control is layout within a table that I have created with gridlayout.. And It has a header in it.. How can I make header template in itemscontrol? So my control will place correctly due to the grid posision on it..?

Comment: if you have one header for each column you could add this header information to your itemssource and put the header binding in your datatemplate too.

Comment: What do you mean `add this header information` ? Can you give me an example?

Comment: i mean the name of the header, eg. ListBlok2B[0].HeaderName = "Header1", ListBlok2B[1].HeaderName = "Header2" ...